# How to Iterate in Symbol Calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my hash:

```
x = {:a1 => "foo", :a2 => "bar", :a3 => "baz"}
```

I'm trying to iterate like x[:aN] in for loop. I tried this but didn't work:

```
for i in 1..5
  x[:a#{"i"}]
end
```

How can I do such a thing?

Comment: What is "iterate like x[:aN] in for loop"? what is ":aN"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really simple:

```
=> x = {:a1 => "foo", :a2 => "bar", :a3 => "baz"}
=> 1.upto(3) { |i| p x[:"a#{i}"]  }
#> "foo"
#> "bar"
#> "baz"
```

Look at example `:a2 == :"a#{2}"` => `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Using you approach:

```
for i in 1..5
  x["a#{"i"}".to_sym]
end
```

Using a more ruby way:

```
keys = x.keys.select { |k| k.to_s.starts_with?("a") }
keys.each { |k| x[k.to_sym] }
```

Comment: The first approach is not working, just printing "1..5".

Comment: that is because the loop returns back the 1..5 (the collection it iterated through) but the inner part gets executed. If you use `puts x["a#{"i"}".to_sym]` you will see your values. Same with the second approach. You don't get a more accurate asnwer because you don't write what you want to get, you just asked how to iterate through them... and that is the way

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way, but you can try this

```
for i in 1..5
  x[('a'+ i.to_s).to_sym]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ActiveSupport [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) wich basically allows to use symbols or strings as the same Hash key:

```
    x = {:a1 => "foo", :a2 => "bar", :a3 => "baz"}
    x1 = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(x)
    for i in 1..5
     x1["a#{i}"]
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:

```
2.1.2 :017 > x = {:a1 => "foo", :a2 => "bar", :a3 => "baz"}
 => {:a1=>"foo", :a2=>"bar", :a3=>"baz"} 
2.1.2 :018 > for i in 1..x.length
2.1.2 :019?>   p x["a#{i}".to_sym]
2.1.2 :020?>   end
"foo"
"bar"
"baz"
```